# How to remove/why is there a dot in the figure number when \part is present?

Tags: floats, numbering, parts

I'm struggling to see the point (pun intended) in having a dot appended to the figure number when a `\part` is involved.

Consider the following MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
\part{Part}
\chapter{Chapter}
\begin{figure}
   This would be the image
   \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The figure number includes a trailing dot, which IMHO isn't needed anyway and I find it conflicting with the colon:

[image: Inappropriate dot]

This dot is added whenever there is a `\part` present in the document, even when the floating environment itself is *not* inside a part (i.e. the first `\part` comes *after* the float, which doesn't make sense but which I tried out to see the behaviour). Commenting out the `\part` produces the numbering I would like to see:

```latex
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}
%\part{Part}
\chapter{Chapter}
\begin{figure}
   This would be the image
   \caption{Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: Correct rendering]

How can I get rid of that dot and how can I understand why it is there in the first place?

[EDIT]:

It seems (as described in the "possible duplicate" suggestion) that in German typography a trailing dot is required when there are non-arabic components in the numbering. While I can see that this is useful in the TOC I find it pretty annoying in float captions because of the clash of the dot and the colon. The non-arabic part numbering isn't a component of that numbering anyway.

[EDIT2]:

The question has been closed as duplicate after I added the first edit (but hadn't highlighted the edit sufficiently. The referenced question did *not* answer my updated question, so essentially this question shouldn't have been closed IMO. However, [This comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/490092/how-to-remove-why-is-there-a-dot-in-the-figure-number-when-part-is-present#comment1238061_490092) *does* answer the question.

Comment: This is a feature of the KOMA-Script classes. If there is a non-arabic sectioning number in the document, the dot appears at the end of the numbers. To get rid of this dots add option `numbers=noenddot`. Default setting is `numbers=auto`.

Comment: Or you only want to remove the auto-dot after the numbers of floats (figure, table etc.)?

Comment: Removing it in the float caption numbering was my intention but I don't care about the dots also being removed in the TOC. So far I can't see if there are other side effects too.

Comment: Well, *for now* I don't care, since the rules seem to be clear that the dot is needed in the TOC at least.

Comment: May be you want the remove the colon in the float caption numbering? Then you can use `\renewcommand*{\captionformat}{~}`.

Comment: This is a good suggestion and would deserve an answer. But I wouldn't want to go that way, especially since I use continuous numbering (i.e. without the chapter number, so it would come out as `Figure 234. Caption`, which I don't like, it should be `Figure 234: Caption`. And of course not `Figure 234.: Caption` either, which is the default.

Comment: If the enddot should only be removed from figure captions itself (and not the numbers in the LoF entries), you could use `\renewcommand*{\figureformat}{\figurename~\thefigure}`. If this does not answer your question, please ask a new question showing the difference to the linked question (duplicate).